# Ошибка "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated" при отправке письма

Tags: visual-studio-2015

VB 2015 не отправляет письмо, выкидывает error:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
    Dim Message As New MailMessage
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("otkogo@gmail.com", "xxxparolxxx")
        SmtpServer.Port = 587
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        mail.To.Add("komu@gmail.com")
        mail.From = New MailAddress("otkogo@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "this is a test mail"
        mail.Body = "some test body stuff"
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
   End Sub
End Class
```

ERROR:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection
>   or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1
>   Authentication Required.

Comment: А данные аутентификации в NetworkCredential точно правильные?